# How to add a Search Bar to a Nested List?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

How can I create a Nested List with a search bar, which should be
located under the title.  For instance, on the fourth Sencha Nested
List example, how would I insert a Search Bar (code below) so that it
looks like this image:

[Sencha Example](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/nested_list)

[image]

Example Search Bar:

```
Ext.define('Sencha.view.SearchBar', {
    extend: 'Ext.Toolbar',
    xtype : 'searchbar',
    requires: ['Ext.field.Text', 'Ext.field.Search'],

    config: {
        ui: 'searchbar',
        layout: 'vbox',

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'title',
                title: 'Search'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'searchfield',
                placeHolder: 'Search...'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add it *after* the Nested List has been instantiated, so the docking position is correct.

```
var nestedList = Ext.create('Ext.NestedList', {
    ...
});

nestedList.add({
    docked: 'top',
    xtype: 'searchbar',
    height: 100
});
```

Comment: I changed the xtype to the user defined 'searchbar' and pasted that into the last Sencha "Live Preview" example on the page I referenced but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to add a reference to the `nestedList`. You also need to give the searchbar a fixed height as it is a vbox (the twitter example adds its height in CSS). Picture: http://rwd.me/Fzlo Source (you can paste it into that live preview): http://rwd.me/FzlK

Comment: That seemed to do it.  Will your source code stay there?  Should you update your answer with the xtype: 'searchbar', height: 100, and remove the title?

Comment: Yes, but I've updated my answer to reflect the searchbar. Thanks.