# Adding a searchfield keyup listener on object creation?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

In another question someone explained how to create a generic search
box for a Nested List.

[How to add a Search Bar to a Nested List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235735/how-to-add-a-search-bar-to-a-nested-list)

How can I add/set a *keyup* listener to this class at the time of creation?
I could add the listener on the class but I want to reuse this class on several screens.

```
Ext.define('Sencha.view.SearchBar', {
    extend: 'Ext.Toolbar',
    xtype : 'searchbar',
    requires: ['Ext.field.Text', 'Ext.field.Search'],

    config: {
        ui: 'searchbar',
        layout: 'vbox',
        cls: 'big',

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'searchfield',
                placeHolder: 'Search...',
                listeners: {
                    scope: this,
                    keyup: function(field) {
                        console.log(field.getValue());
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Can I add the listener directly to the searchfield at this point?

```
var searchBar = nestedList.add({
    docked: 'top',
    xtype: 'searchbar',
    height: 100
});
```

I also tried adding a listener like this but I think I need to be able to access the field directly

```
searchBar.on('keyup', function(field) {
                  console.log("foo...");
                  console.log(field.getValue());
                }, this);
```

====================================

[Update]
Adding the delegation to the class:

```
Ext.define('Sencha.view.SearchBar', {
    extend: 'Ext.Toolbar',
    xtype : 'searchbar',
    requires: ['Ext.field.Text', 'Ext.field.Search'],
    config: {
        ui: 'searchbar',
        layout: 'vbox',
        cls: 'big',

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'searchfield',
                placeHolder: 'Search...'
            }
        ]
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.on({
            scope: this,
            delegate: 'searchfield',
            keyup: 'onSearchFieldKeyUp'
        });
    },
    onSearchFieldKeyUp: function(field) {
        console.log("Base Class");
        console.log(field.getValue());
    }
});
```

**Next instantiate 'searchbar' with our own method to override default *onSearchFieldKeyUp***

```
 var searchBar = this.nestedList.add({
            docked: 'top',
            xtype: 'searchbar',
            height: 75,
            id: 'searchbarId'

        });
```

Comment: Try it. What is preventing you from trying?

Comment: I'm a little new to Javascript.  Sorry if I'm missing the obvious.  Are you just saying add listeners:{} right after the height: 100?  I'll give that a try...

Comment: What I described didn't work.  I included all of the source code.  I think I need to directly address the searchfield from items:[].

Comment: To answer your original question, I think it's the Javascript issue of changing something all day long without any error messages as to what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the listener inside the `initialize` function in your class:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.on({
        scope: this,
        delegate: 'searchbar',
        keyup: 'onSearchFieldKeyUp'
    });
},

onSearchFieldKeyUp: function(field) {
    console.log(field.getValue());
}
```

Notice I'm using the `delegate` property to add the listener onto the searchfield component (via `xtype`);

Comment: I don't see how this helps for each instance of SearchBar.  Couldn't find any Sencha docs on it either.  This is a typo in your answer, right?  I'm not missing something?  onSearchFieldKeyUp != onSearchKeyFieldKeyUp.  Delegates in native code are used for callbacks.  I don't see where I'm setting up a callback on a given instance.

Comment: Sorry, yes; that was a typo (fixed). The delegate should also be `searchbar` (your xtype). `delegate` in this case means it will add the listener to that delegate, which can be a ComponentQuery.

Comment: In my question, I added your changes at the update.  I still don't get what I'm suppose to do so I get some sort of delegation.  I bolded where I'm confused.  Something should override my initial "Base Class" method and delegate control to each instantiation?

Comment: Inside `onSearchFieldKeyUp` fire the keyup event. `this.fireEvent('keyup', this, field.getValue());` - then you can add a listener to your instance for that event.